# Getting all one's 2012 shares with FQL

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-fql

I need to retrieve among other data all the shares a person has done on his facebook account during the past year, 2012 in my case.

I found that shares are accessible via FQL table named "stream", selecting stream.type = 80. Using also the where clause on "created_time" and source_id should do the trick :

```
SELECT post_id,message,likes,attachment 
FROM stream 
WHERE source_id = me() 
AND created_time > 1325397600 
AND type=80 
ORDER BY likes.count desc
```

Fact is... When querying the stream table, facebook's engine seems to need a limit. If you don't provide one, no result. I guess it's because if no limit is set, response times could be veeeery long... Anyway I'm sure they have many reasons for that. So :

```
SELECT post_id,message,likes,attachment 
FROM stream 
WHERE source_id = me() 
AND created_time > 1325397600 
AND type=80 
ORDER BY likes.count desc 
LIMIT 100
```

**But**: this limit parameter seems to be applied *before* some of my where clauses, unlike in SQL statements such as SQL server, it means that what fb does with my example query is sequentially :

- take 100 elements from stream quite randomly, of any type (could be status, shares, photos, places, posts on your wall from friends, etc.) and any time. Actually, my source_id clause seems to be applied before limit.
- then filter by type 80 and created_time, but not sure how

In my case, I need all shares from year 2012, but I can never be sure that some arbitrary limit set to 2000 or 5000 will catch all one's 2012 stream elements before applying the filter.

Maybe there is an other way ?

Thanks a lot for your help.